# Finite group with at most one subgroup for each order.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group.
I want to prove the following propositon.

> If for every positive integer $n$, the number of subgroups of $G$ of order $n$ is $1$ or $0$, then $G$ is
>   cyclic.

Is my proof right?

$$\begin{align*}
f(d)&＝\text{The number of element of }G\text{ of order }n\\
&\leq(\text{number of subgroups of order }d)\times(\text{number of generators of }G)
\end{align*}$$

Above inequality holds for any finite group $G$.

From assumption, we can deduce
$$f(d)\leq \text{number of generators of }G = \varphi(d)$$

On the other hand, $n$ is the sum of $f(d)$ where $d$ divides $n$.

And the sum is less than the sum of $\varphi(d)$ where $d$ divides $n$. And the last sum is $n$, so, $f(d)=\varphi(d)$.

In particular, $f(n)=\varphi(n)\geq 1$, so $G$ has an element $a$ which has order $n$. Therefore, $G=\langle a\rangle$.

Comment: at most one or less than one?

Comment: I meant at most one.I edited, thank you.

Comment: You have not stated the question correctly. You want the hypothesis to hold for all natural numbers $n$, not just for some $n$ of your choice.

Comment: Of course n is arbitrary and my proof assumes that.

Comment: 'For each order' I stated correctly.

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is finite? And your question is indeed not stated correctly. And I recommend using MathJax.

Comment: Look the title.

Comment: The question body should be self contained. -1

Comment: @buoyant. Please, don't feel offended. It is true that there is almost ample description and indication in the title and question body but communication is the key here so that everyone can enjoy your problem. If there is a small change you can make that actually makes sense and clarifies your problem for future readers then maybe you can just make the edit and let it go. Of course everyone wants to be respected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument has a bunch of typos and omissions,  and is not very clear, but is essentially correct.

You define $f(d)$ to be the number of elements of order exactly $d$ in $G$. Then we note that if $x$ is an element of order $d$, then so are $x^a$ for any $a$, $1\leq a\leq d$, $\gcd(a,d)=1$; so each element of order $d$ gives you $\varphi(d)$ other elements of order $d$. Now, if $H$ is a subgroup of order $d$, then if it is cyclic it contains exactly $\varphi(d)$ elements of order $d$, and if it is not cyclic, then it contains $0$, and hence fewer than $\varphi(d)$ elements. Each element of order $d$ is counted this way.

That means that $f(d)$ is, at most, the number of subgroups of order $d$ times $\varphi(d)$. The typos in your first equation are:

1. The $n$ on the first line; and
2. It's not "generators of $G$", in the second line, it's generators of the subgroup of order $d$.

Now, since by assumption there is at most one subgroup of order $d$, that means that $f(d)\leq\varphi(d)$ for each $d$. That's correct.

Since $|G|=\sum_{d|n}f(d)$, then
$$n = |G|=\sum_{d|n}f(d) \leq\sum_{d|n}\varphi(d).$$
But it is known that $\sum_{d|n}\varphi(d) = n$, so we have equality throughout. In particular, for every $d|n$, $f(d)=\varphi(d)$. That's correct, though poorly worded.

And then you conclude that since $\varphi(n)\geq 1$, then $f(n)\geq 1$, which means $G$ contains at least one element of order $n$, and thus is cyclic. Again, correct.

Answer (score -2):

Let $p_1^{r_1}\cdot p_2^{r_2}\cdots p_n^{r_n}$ be the prime factorization of $m:=\text{exp}(G)$. Each cyclic $G$ subgroup $\langle g\rangle$ must also be a normal $G$ subgroup as it is the unique cyclic subgroup of that order. Choose $g_1,g_2,\dots ,g_n\in G$ such that $\text{ord}(g_i)=p_i^{r_i}$ and compose the internal direct sum $$\langle g_0\rangle:=\langle g_1\rangle\oplus\langle g_2\rangle\oplus\cdots\oplus\langle g_n\rangle$$ Finally, given any $g\in G$ then $m=\text{ord}(g_0)$ is a multiple of $|\langle g\rangle|$ which must equal the size of a $\langle g_0\rangle$ subgroup so that we may conclude $\langle g\rangle\subseteq\langle g_0\rangle$. Therefore $G=\langle g_0\rangle$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin. I'm using the fact that all cyclic $G$ subgroups are normal.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin. Firstly, let's try to be civil and respect each other. I won't dignify your comments on my personal character but I will elucidate again the group theory again so that you understand  me and to set an example for others.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin. If you read closely you see that I edited my response purposely to meet the "question" you left for me. There's nothing confusing about it. Secondly, the last claim is indeed warranted. Think about it again. Hint : the exponent of $G$ is obtained by taking the least common multiple of the orders of the group elements. Therefore, each $p_i^{r_i}$ must indeed divide the order of a group element.

Comment: I will delete some of the comments above, but for future reference, here is what your first comment could have been to avoid all of this: `@ArturoMagidin: I have edited the question.`. That’s all. Or `I have edited the question; now I am using that cyclic subgroups must me normal.`. That makes it clear the question precedes the edit, and the answer follows the edit. And if the question is no longer relevant, then I can delete the comment, but until I do, everyone can easily see the sequence of events.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin. I feel you should also apologize for your characterization of me.  You could have made your concern clear, just like I did, without the insolence. "everyone can easily see the sequence of events" (indeed).

Comment: I have said all I plan to say.